# Removing duplicate in list of map based on two keys

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of map 
entries in map looks like this

```
{
   key1:A;
   key2:3;
   key3:10;
}
{
   key1:A;
   key2:3;
   key3:5;
}
{
   key1:A;
   key2:6;
   key3:5;
}
{
   key1:A;
   key2:6;
   key3:10;
}
```

key1+key2 makes a composite key and there can be either one or two entry in list regarding one composite key.

So, if there are multiple entries in list , entry with lesser value has to be taken.

How to solve this problem in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
var ret = new List; // to contain resulting entries
var seen = new Set; // to keep track of what composite keys has been
                    // seen already (and, as such, included into the
                    // resulting list
foreach (inList as elt) { // iterate over the incoming list
   if (!seen.has({key1: elt.key1, key2: elt.key2})) { // check key1,key2 composite key has already been seen
       // append to `ret` list and mark as seen
       seen.add({key1: elt.key1, key2: elt.key2}); 
       ret.add(elt);
   }
}
return ret; // return the result - assuming it's in a function body
```

Time complexity is O(n) (assuming List and Set append operations are O(1)), and space complexity is O(n) (approximately 3 times of the incoming list size)

Comment: I am not sure how you are using sets. In Sets we only give one value.. right. how are you checking combination of two values in set.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: hey can you provide java equivalent for  if (!seen.has({key1: elt.key1, key2: elt.key2}))  line.  How are you checking key1,key2 composite key has already been seen. In java .contains() take only one key as input. not two keys

Comment: This very much depends on how sets behave with 'plain' objects in your language of choice (you only added the language tag after I posted the answer). Here, I check a single value on every iteration: `{ key1 : "...", key2 : "..."}`, assuming the Set.append() method would invoke its `.equals` method, and `.equals` would compare all properties.

For Java, I imagine, you would add an anonymous class declaring `.equals` where I used object literal ( `{ key1: "...", key2: "..." }` )

Comment: and this logic will take value corresponding to composite key which appeared first. not  with lesser value.